# Spark timestamp column value comparison

Tags: apache-spark-sql

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx62C.jpg) I want to filter out the rows which have the `date_time_begin` is less than the start date and i have tried this but i am not getting any output. I am using the spark 1.6.2 version

```
 filterddata = joindedf.filter(joindedf("date_time_begin").gt(lit("str_date")))
 filterddata.show()
```

Comment: Can you share the input data as well ??

Comment: Thanks:) Shankar Koirala  Added the sample data

Comment: What is the datatype of both columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the `columns` are of the same `datatype` this should work.

```
val filterddata = joindedf.filter(joindedf("date_time_begin").gt(joindedf("str_date")))
```

`lit` is used to convert the literal value as a `column`.

I hope this helped!